# Add repitition as list in case class (scala parser)

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I have following parser:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.RegexParsers

class SimpleParser extends RegexParsers {

  override val skipWhitespace = false

  private val eol = sys.props("line.separator")

  def word: Parser[String] = "[a-z]+".r ^^ { _.toString }

  def freq: Parser[List[String]] = repsep(word, eol) ^^ {
    case word => word
  }

}

object TestSimpleParser extends SimpleParser {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    parse(freq,
      """mike
        |john
        |sara
      """.stripMargin) match {
      case Success(matched,_) => println(matched)
      case Failure(msg,_) => println(msg)
      case Error(msg,_) => println(msg)
    }
  }
}
```

The result of this execution will be `List(mike, john, sara)` but it isn't what i want.

I'd like to have the following case class:

```
case class SomeEntity(list: List[String])
```

And the result will be the following:

```
SomeEntity(List(mike), List(john), List(sara)).
```

I want to add as much Lists as there are words with new lines.
Please, don't put a big attention on the fact that there is just one word in a list. It is just a simplified version of my issue. 
So, what should i change in the parser or in case class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case class definition does not match your expected output. You're looking for this:

```
case class SomeEntity(list: List[String]*) {
    override def toString = this.getClass.getSimpleName+"("+list.mkString(", ")+")"
}
```

Now if, you want to get back a `SomeEntity` instance, the type of the Parser will be `Parser[SomeEntity]`.

As `repsep` will give you back a `List[String]`, you need to map each element in the list into a singleton list (so that you get a `List[List[String]]`) and then you forces it to see it as a varargs type with `:_*`

```
 def freq: Parser[SomeEntity] = 
     repsep(word, eol) ^^ (list => new SomeEntity(list.map(List(_)) : _*))
```

Given your input, it outputs:

```
SomeEntity(List(mike), List(john), List(sara))
```

Your case class could also take a `List[List[String]]` as parameter. Although a `List[String]` would be the most correct type in my opinion, but you certainly have reasons to require this.

Note that your mapping with the `word` parser is redundant, you could remove it.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It should have SomeEntity(List(mike), List(john), List(sara). It is just a simplify version of my problem, so please don't look at one word in a list here.

Comment: @perc The signature of your case class does not match the expected result, you should update it accordingly.

Comment: Could you tell me what should i change in case class?

Comment: isn't is case class SomeEntity(list1: List[S], list2: List[S], list3: List[S])  But if i will have a lot of strings, i want to add dynamically